# PETSc: Blocking matrices using MatCreateSeqBAIJ and MatSetValuesBlocked

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, sparse-matrix, petsc

I am a little confused with PETSc's documentation for `MatSetValuesBlocked`. The code below works fine for matrices when I choose small block sizes, but I get errors when using bigger block sizes for the same matrix. The two main questions:

1) What is the right way to use `MatSetValuesBlocked`?

2) What is the correct way to generate `idxn` and `idxm`, global indices for the row and column blocks, respectively. As an example, for a matrix with m=n=20 and block size = 2, are idxn and idxm = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ?

Not sure if there's a mistake in any other function, but I'd like to know what I am doing wrong!

Thanks!

```
    MatCreateSeqBAIJ(PETSC_COMM_SELF,bs,m,n,nnz*2/m,0,&A);
    MatSetOption(A,MAT_NEW_NONZERO_ALLOCATION_ERR,PETSC_FALSE);
    PetscInt idxm[(m/bs)] ; //row index of total number of blocks
    PetscInt idxn[(m/bs)] ; //column index of total number of blocks

    /*Values from the sparsematrix.mtx file */

    for (i=0; i<nnz; i++) 
    {
     fscanf(file,"%d %d %le\n",&row,&col,(double*)&val);
     values[i] =  val;
    }
    fclose(file);



/*Constructing idxm */ 

   for(m_index=0; m_index< (m/bs); m_index++) //Number of blocks rowwise
   {
        idxm[m_index] = m_index; // For the blocks in the first row

   } //idxm construction complete


 /*Constructing idxn*/



  for(b_index = 0; b_index < (n/bs) ; b_index ++) //Each column for each block
  {
    idxn[b_index] = b_index;

  } //idxn construction complete.

  /*Errors occur..*/
  MatSetValuesBlocked(A,m/bs,idxm,n/bs,idxn, values, INSERT_VALUES);

  MatAssemblyBegin(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);
  MatAssemblyEnd(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);

  PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_SELF,"Reading matrix completed....\n");

  PetscOptionsGetString(NULL,"-fout",fileout,PETSC_MAX_PATH_LEN,NULL);
  PetscViewerBinaryOpen(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,fileout,FILE_MODE_WRITE,&view);
  MatView(A,view);
  VecView(b,view);

  MatMult(A, b, res); //Actual multiplication

  PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_SELF,"Matmult completed...\n");
  PetscViewerDestroy(&view);
  ierr = VecDestroy(&b);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatDestroy(&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDestroy(&res);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscRandomDestroy(&r);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFinalize();
```

Answer (score 3):

`MatSetValuesBlocked` contributes logically dense blocks.  Given the pattern shown above, you should be calling it once per block-row.  You're currently calling it as though the arguments were COO format.

Also be aware that reading a matrix from a file is a workflow choice that guarantees that your software will never be scalable.  Long-term, you should choose a way to avoid using the file system during matrix assembly.

Comment: Thanks! I revised the insertion but I am still missing something:
`for(i=0; i<m/bs; i++) //For each blocked row:  
  {  
  MatSetValuesBlocked(A,2,&idxm[i],n/bs,idxn, &values[i][0], INSERT_VALUES);  
  } `

Comment: What is `bs`, what `m`, what is `n`, and how is `values` packed?